# React.js input dropdown selection, state management and event handling

Tags: reactjs

I want the user to be able to track his medicine. Therefore I have several input fields, which all have the same OnChange event handler (addNewMed). This is used to generate an object with all input data.
Now I also would like the user to get a suggestion when typing the medicine name in the input box. I have a function which searches a .json file to give the user a suggestion. If user clicks on suggestion, I want to  put this selection directly in the input field. So now this is the problem. How can I combine this with my onChange event handler, which then generates the newMedItem object.

Thanks!

```
const [newMedItem, setNewMedItem]=useState({
  name: "",
  dosage: "",
  interval: "",
  date:"",
  enddate:""
 });

const addNewMed = function(event){
  const value=event.target.value; 
 setNewMedItem({
  ...newMedItem,
  [event.target.name]: value
 }) 
}

<input type="text" name ="name" value={newMedItem.name} onChange={addNewMed} placeholder="Add new Medication"/>
         
<div className="dropdown">
    if(val.label?.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm?.toLowerCase()))
          {return val}
    }).map((val, key)=>{
    return(
       <div key={key} onClick={handleMedSelection}>
       {val.label}
            </div>
          )
         })}

<input type="text"  name="dosage" value={newMedItem.dosage} onChange={addNewMed} placeholder="Add Dosage"/>
<input type="text"  name="interval" value={newMedItem.interval} onChange={addNewMed} placeholder="Add Interval"/>
 <input type="date"  name="date" value={newMedItem.date} onChange={addNewMed} placeholder="Add Start Date"/>
<input type="date" name="enddate" value={newMedItem.enddate} onChange={addNewMed} placeholder="Add End Date"/>
```

Comment: where is your suggestion function? if you provide codesandbox, it would be great

Comment: Sure, this is a link to CodeSandbox: https://io6r9v.csb.app/. Thanks!

Comment: I have answer, you can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that I'm late to the party, but my answer might be useful for another reader. Let's do it without further ado.

We assume that this medicine list is a draft that will be sent to the server once confirmed by the user by clicking submit button. Where before submission, the user can add, edit or even delete the medicine from the draft.

Note: we use [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) for a clean css implementation.

### Setup

Let's say, your object of medicine structure is like this:

```json
{
  value: n,
  label: 'string',
}
```

For learning purposes, here we will use an API from [https://api.fda.go](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?count=openfda.brand_name.exact&limit=1000).
We will fetch the medicines list from this API endpoint and store the results inside the **medicines** state with the above medicine object structure.

```js
  const [medicines, setMedicines] = useState([]);
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?count=openfda.brand_name.exact&limit=1000"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (response) => {
          setMedicines(
            response.results.map((result, i) => {
              return {
                value: i,
                label: result.term,
              };
            })
          );
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);
```

Now we already have our medicines data that will become the raw information for our draft.

### Dropdown Selection

Ideally, a dropdown list will have an **input** and **list items** where our medicines list resides. Both of them are wrapped inside a `div` that will have a **relative** position and the list items' positions must be an **absolute** position. Our list item would have a **tabIndex** too for the sake of UX.

##### 1. The input

Create a **query state** that will become the holder of our input value and use the query state as the value of our input. Then define a **handleQuery** function that is passed onto the input onChange handler plus **onKeydown** handler that listens to input **pageDown** event.

```
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  const handleQuery = (event) => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleOnInputKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 40) {   // pageDown keyCode
      event.preventDefault();
      event.target.nextSibling.firstChild.focus(); // focus on the list items first child
    }
  };

  <input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    placeholder="Add new Medication"
    value={query}
    onChange={handleQuery}
    onKeyDown={handleOnInputKeyDown}
    className="w-96 h-8 p-3 border-2"
  />
```

##### 2. The List Items

List Items will use a memoized **filtereMedicines** that depends on **medicines** and **query** state. So, the list items' contents will change on any query state changes and will be rendered by using javascript's map method.
Here, we added **isShowMedicines** state helper as a show/hide reference of our medicines list and insert the setter into **handleQuery** function.

```js
  const [isShowMedicines, setIsShowMedicines] = useState(false);

  const handleQuery = (event) => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
    setIsShowMedicines(true); // set to true to show the list items
  };
  ...
  const filteredMedicines = useMemo(() => {
    return medicines.filter((medicine) =>
      medicine.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
    );
  }, [medicines, query]);
 
  ...

  return (
    ...
      {isShowMedicines && (
          <ul className="w-96 border-2 absolute top-8 z-50 bg-white max-h-96 overflow-auto">
            {filteredMedicines.map((medicine, i) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={i}
                  onKeyDown={(event) => handleOnKeyDown(event, medicine)}
                  className="px-3 py-1 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100"
                  onClick={() => handleSelectMedicine(medicine)}
                  tabIndex={i}
                >
                  {medicine.label}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
      ...
    )
  }
```

We add **handleSelectMedicine** and **handleOnKeyDown** functions for a better user experience.

```js
  // update the query state and hide the list items
  const handleSelectMedicine = (medicine) => {
    setQuery(medicine.label);
    setIsShowMedicines(false);
  };

  const handleOnKeyDown = (event, medicine) => {
    // prevent the default scroll behaviour
    event.preventDefault();

    const {
      keyCode,
      target: { nextSibling, previousSibling, parentElement },
    } = event;

    // focus to the next list item when pageDown pressed
    if (keyCode === 40 && nextSibling) {
      nextSibling.focus();
    }

    if (keyCode === 38) {
      if (previousSibling) {
        // focus to the available previous list item when pageUp pressed
        previousSibling.focus();
      } else {
        // focus to the input element when no more list item
        parentElement.previousSibling.focus();
      }
    }

    // update query state with currently focused list item and hide the list items 
    if (keyCode === 13) {
      handleSelectMedicine(medicine);
    }
  };
```

Tada! Now you already have your own **Dropdown List** with a better looking. Isn't it?

### State Management & Event Handling

Next, we add two more states here:

1. Medicine state, that will become the placeholder for medicine that will be used for adding or editing patient medicine by the user.
2. Patient Medicines state, that will hold the patient medicine list that will be sent to the server.

```js
const DEFAULT_DATA = {
  name: "",
  dosage: "",
  interval: "",
  date: "",
  endDate: "",
};

const [medicine, setMedicine] = useState(DEFAULT_DATA);
const [patientMedicines, setPatientMedicines] = useState([]);
```

Then we add the other inputs and their related handler functions

```
  const updateMedicine = (name, value) => {
    setMedicine((prevState) => {
      prevState[name] = value;
      return { ...prevState };
    });
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    updateMedicine(name, value);
  };

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <input
      type="text"
      name="dosage"
      value={medicine.dosage}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      className="w-96 h-8 p-3 border-2 mt-3"
      placeholder="Add Dosage"
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      name="interval"
      value={medicine.interval}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      className="w-96 h-8 p-3 border-2 mt-3"
      placeholder="Add Interval"
    />
    <input
      type="date"
      name="date"
      value={medicine.date}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      className="w-96 h-8 p-3 border-2 mt-3"
      placeholder="Add Start Date"
    />
    <input
      type="date"
      name="endDate"
      value={medicine.endDate}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      className="w-96 h-8 p-3 border-2 mt-3"
      placeholder="Add End Date"
    />
  ...
  )
```

Here, when the user changes one of the inputs, the **handleInputChange** handler will update the **medicine** state by using **updateMedicine** function. But remember that the **medicine** input use a different **onChange** handler which is **handleQuery**. So to update **medicine.name** we use a **useEffect** hook block that watches the **query** state and performs the **medicine** state updates when the **query** state changes.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    updateMedicine("name", query);
  }, [query]);
```

To add a new medicine object into **patientMedicines** array, we add an **Add Button** that has **onCLick** listener and pass **addNewMedicine** function to it.

```js
  const addNewMedicine = useCallback(() => {
    setPatientMedicines((prevState) => {
      return [...prevState, medicine]; // clone prevState and add medicine
    });
  }, [medicine]);

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <button
      className="h-8 w-36 my-3 border-2 rounded-sm bg-gray-200"
      onClick={addNewMedicine}
    >
      Add Medicine
    </button>
  )
```

Once a new **medicine** added into **patientMedicines** list, **patienceMedicines** state will change and we use this event to reset our inputs:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setQuery("");
    setMedicine({ ...DEFAULT_DATA });
  }, [patientMedicines]);
```

Now, it is time to render our **patientMedicines** list by using a plain table. We add a **Delete** button into the **medicine** row and add **handleDeleteMedicine** handler to it.

```
    ...

    const handleDeleteMedicine = useCallback(
    (index) => {
      setPatientMedicines(
        patientMedicines.filter((_medicines, i) => i !== index)
      );
    },
    [patientMedicines]
  );

  return (
     ...
     <table className="mt-5">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="h-12 bg-gray-200">Medicine Name</th>
            <th className="h-12 bg-gray-200">Dosage</th>
            <th className="h-12 bg-gray-200">Interval</th>
            <th className="h-12 bg-gray-200">Date</th>
            <th className="h-12 bg-gray-200">End Date</th>
            <th className="h-12 bg-gray-200">Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {patientMedicines.map((patientMedicine, i) => {
            return (
              <tr key={i} className="h-10 border">
                <td className="px-3">{patientMedicine.name}</td>
                <td className="px-3">{patientMedicine.dosage}</td>
                <td className="px-3">{patientMedicine.interval}</td>
                <td className="px-3 w-36">{patientMedicine.date}</td>
                <td className="px-3 w-36">{patientMedicine.endDate}</td>
                <td className="px-3 w-36">
                  <button
                    className="h-8 w-20 my-3 border-2 rounded-sm bg-gray-200"
                    onClick={() => handleDeleteMedicine(i)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      ...
   )
```

How about editing the **patientMedicines** list?. Here we add **isEditing** state, **handleEditMedicine** function, and **editMedicine** function.

```
  const [editIndex, setEditIndex] = useState();

  const isEditing = useMemo(() => {
    return editIndex === undefined ? false : true;
  }, [editIndex]);

  const handleEditMedicine = useCallback(
    (index) => {
      setEditIndex(index);
      const editingMedicine = patientMedicines[index];
      setQuery(editingMedicine.name);
      setMedicine({ ...editingMedicine });
    },
    [patientMedicines]
  );

  const editMedicine = useCallback(() => {
    patientMedicines[editIndex] = medicine;
    setPatientMedicines([...patientMedicines]);
    setEditIndex();
  }, [editIndex, medicine, patientMedicines]);
```

and conditionally render the **Add Button** and **Edit Button** based on **isEditing** state. Don't forget to add **Submit** button at the bottom of your table, to submit your data to the server. Here we use to log the current **patientMedicines** data.

```
  ...
return (
  <div>
  ...
    <table>
      {isEditing ? (
        <button
          className="h-8 w-36 my-3 border-2 rounded-sm bg-gray-200"
          onClick={editMedicine}
        >
          Edit Medicine
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button
          className="h-8 w-36 my-3 border-2 rounded-sm bg-gray-200"
          onClick={addNewMedicine}
        >
          Add Medicine
        </button>
      )}
    ...
    </table>
    <button
      className="h-8 w-20 my-3 border-2 rounded-sm bg-gray-200"
      onClick={() => console.log(patientMedicines)}
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
)
```

Finally, here is the complete code:

[image: Edit hardcore-neumann-3bhsob]

Answer (score 0):

You can filter dropdownList by `newMedItem.name`

```
const dropDownList = fdaList.list.filter((val) => {
    if (newMedItem.name === "") {
      return true;
    } else if (
      val.label?.toLowerCase().includes(newMedItem.name?.toLowerCase())
    ) {
      return true;
    }
});
```

Full code should be like this

```
export default function Main() {
  const defaultMedItem = {
    name: "",
    dosage: "",
    interval: "",
    date: "",
    enddate: ""
  };

  const [newMedItem, setNewMedItem] = useState(defaultMedItem);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const addNewMed = function (event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setNewMedItem({
      ...newMedItem,
      [event.target.name]: value
    });
    console.log(newMedItem);
  };

  const handleMedSelection = function (event) {
    setNewMedItem({
      ...newMedItem,
      name: ""
    });
  };

  const dropDownList = fdaList.list.filter((val) => {
    if (newMedItem.name === "") {
      return true;
    } else if (
      val.label?.toLowerCase().includes(newMedItem.name?.toLowerCase())
    ) {
      return true;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="addItem">
        <h3>Add new Medication</h3>
        <form className="row addItemForm">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="newMed col-3"
            name="name"
            value={newMedItem.name}
            onChange={addNewMed}
            placeholder="Add new Medication"
          />

          <div className="dropdown">
            {newMedItem.name.length >= 2 &&
              dropDownList.map((val, key) => {
                return (
                  <div key={key} onClick={handleMedSelection}>
                    {val.label}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
          </div>

          <input
            type="text"
            className="newMed col-3"
            name="dosage"
            value={newMedItem.dosage}
            onChange={addNewMed}
            placeholder="Add Dosage"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="newMed col-2"
            name="interval"
            value={newMedItem.interval}
            onChange={addNewMed}
            placeholder="Add Interval"
          />
          <input
            type="date"
            className="newMed col-2"
            name="date"
            value={newMedItem.date}
            onChange={addNewMed}
            placeholder="Add Start Date"
          />
          <input
            type="date"
            className="newMed col-2"
            name="enddate"
            value={newMedItem.enddate}
            onChange={addNewMed}
            placeholder="Add End Date"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-rgb-jctx98?file=/src/App.js:126-2603). Hope it help!